# Combine array form set of values and keys

Tags: php, arrays

Hello everybody out there using php!

I have been searching for an answer.
I have two arrays - Persons and other array of indexes from Persons array.

```
Persons(array)           Selected indexes(array)
  [0] => 'Mark'            [0] => 0
  [1] => 'Jane'            [1] => 2
  [2] => 'Bob'             [2] => 1
  [3] => 'Jack'
```

I want to create a third array that consists only the elements from `Persons` array that are set in `Selected indexes` array. 
Sort of like `SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE 'Persons id' IN 'Selected indexes'` but in PHP if you know what i mean ?

I could "foreach" the latter and push elements to the new array, but is there a shorter php solution e.g. for inline usage ?

Edit: Oh, and the output should be:

```
Selected persons(array)           
  [0] => 'Mark'            
  [1] => 'Jane'           
  [2] => 'Bob'      

(only 0, 2 and 1)
```

Comment: A combination of array_combine() with array_slice() and min() and count() should do the trick

Comment: http://php.net/array_intersect should get you started, though it won't directly do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = array_intersect_key($people, array_flip($selected));
```

Comment: This is just the right thing! Thank you! I try to keep my eyes more open when browsing manual.

Answer (score 1):

@Steve has already posted the cleanest way to do this, here's an alternative

```
$counter = min(count($selected), count($persons));
$result = array_combine(
    array_slice($selected, 0, $counter),
    array_slice($persons, 0, $counter) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you!

```
<?php

    $person = array('Mark', 'Jane', 'Bob', 'Jack');
    $selected = array(0, 2, 1);
    $selectedPerson = array();


    foreach($selected as $key)
        $selectedPerson[] =  $person[$key];

    var_dump($selectedPerson);  

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

array_intersect_key() is what you are looking for

```
$Persons[0]='Mark'; 
$Persons[1]='Jane';
$Persons[2]='Bob';
$Persons[3]='Jack';

$Selected = array(0,2);

$result = array_intersect_key($Persons, array_flip($Selected))

var_dump($result); // returns Mark, Bob.
```